# Keras Neural Network: use loss from one output in the loss of the other output

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use the loss from one of my NN auxiliary outputs as part of the loss for the other output.

$L($total$) = L($main output$) - \lambda L($auxiliary output$)$

I am unsure how to access the auxiliary loss when creating a custom loss function, as shown in the "# define custom loss" section in my code:

```
# multi-ouput NN
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model 
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

# initialize input tensor
input = Input(shape=(128,), name='input') # tell Keras the shape of the input per batch

# initialize passes
encoded_data = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='encoded_data')(input) 
classified_data = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='classified_data')(encoded_data) 
predicted_data = Dense(128, activation='softmax', name='predicted_data')(encoded_data) 

# define model with one input and two outputs
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=[classified_data, predicted_data])

# define custom loss
def custom_loss(layer):

    # create loss that incorporate loss from classification layer, lambda = 0.1
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) - (0.1)*K.categorical_crossentropy(layer), axis=-1)

    # Return a function
    return loss

# compile the model 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss={'classified_data': 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                    'predicted_data': custom_loss(classified_data)})
```

Any ideas? I have used this as a guide for creating custom losses of this type, but can't quite get it to work:

https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-keras-constructing-complex-custom-losses-and-metrics-c07ca130a618